# Alternative TTS engine?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an android app that has a very nice voice when speaking English, and it is a different voice from the one in my tablet by default (Google TTS)

How did they do that ? Is it possible to download tts packages, and integrate them in an app easily ?
I managed to do text to speech easily with the user's default built in tts, but I have no idea where to start for changing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are third part companies that allow you to use their embedded voice engines, or alternatively use their RESTful services to generate the voice audio. Here are some useful links:

1. [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/)
2. [NEO Speech](http://www.neospeech.com/)
3. [IVONA](http://developer.ivona.com/)
4. [Nunance](http://www.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/)
5. [AT&T](http://developer.att.com/apis/speech)
6. [Acapela](http://www.acapela-group.com/)
7. [Cereproc](https://www.cereproc.com/)

There are some other providers out there that will offer voices for free, but they are of a much lower quality. You get what you pay for....

Comment: The last time I checked. The most human sounding voice was Ivona (owned by Amazon). Unfortunately, they wanted developers to contact their sales staff before they'd give out any kind of price (which I didn't do).

Comment: so nothing to train to speak with your own voice ? :(
Thanks anyway