# Android: How to develop App for TTS languages not supported on phones

Tags: android, text-to-speech, multiple-languages

I just completed a voice recognition and Text-To-Speech (TTS) translation app. 
However, I noticed that the TTS portion will not work for TTS languages not installed on my phone or if the TTS Engine does not include that particular language.

There are numerous Translation apps which provide TTS in many different languages without the need for these languages to be installed on the phones. Would anyone be kind to advice me on how I can incorporate such a feature in my app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At last, a fine question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind paying for the services, you can use any one of the providers [I list in my answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22746880/1256219). There are many languages available collectively.

Alternatively, you could use the Chrome Speech API - but it's unofficial and therefore probably not a great idea for a production app.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=This%20is%20a%20test